# DIV aligning vertically and horizontally in center of a relative positioned DIV

Tags: html, css

i have two div in my Page, 
which seems to be working fine with the vertically and horizontally center aligning but  resize the browser vertically that the divs aren't responding by growing or shrinking, i am assuming it because of the margin:auto; but can't find a way to solve this issue, can any you guys help please?

CSS as follows:

```
#outer {    
width: 100%;    
height: 417px;  
position:relative;  
background-color:#666; 
}

 #inner {
height: 300px;  
width:50%;  
background-color: #F00;
position:absolute;  
left:0;     
right:0;    
top:0;  
bottom:0;
margin:auto;    
height:240px;   }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5dqUL/)

Comment: Can you post your relevant HTML and CSS code in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) please?

Comment: The way you have it set up right now, you are doing an auto margin for the top/bottom AND right/left. If you only want to center horizontally so that the inner div has top:0 you need to do `margin:0 auto;` [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4hWhm/)

Comment: then it will align on the top, it won't align in the center :(

Comment: Are you saying that when you resize the browser vertically that the divs aren't responding by growing or shrinking?

Comment: @LaughDonor here it goes bro, http://jsfiddle.net/5dqUL/

Comment: @APAD1 yes exactly i meant that

Comment: To understand correctly, you want to make it so when you resize the browser, the divs grow/shrink?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your divs height to a relative value (percentages):

```
html, body, #outer{
  height: 100%;
}

#outer {
  width: 100%;
  position:relative;
}

#inner {
  height: 60%;
  width:50%;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `margin:auto` is fine. The issue is your fixed height, and also the fact that your have two `height` attributes. You should set your dimensions to percentage values.

This is the mended code:

```
 #outer {    
width: 100%;    
height: 417px; 
position:relative;  
background-color:#666; 
}
#inner {
height: 50%; // This equals to 50% of 417px, which is height of #outer 
width:50%;  
background-color: #F00;
position:absolute;  
left:0;     
right:0;    
top:0;  
bottom:0;
margin:auto;    
   }
```